# Problems generating gif using raster package and google map images R

Tags: r, gis, animated-gif, r-raster

I want to generate a gif from raster images using imagemagick convert.

I use as a background a google map so I need to call plot() twice and this generated a flickering in the resulting gif, because a blank image is inserted in each cycle. How can I eliminate this blank image and generate a smooth gif?

An example follows:

```
require(raster)
require(dismo)

bk<-gmap(c(" DR Congo"))
png(file="Rplot%03d.png", width=500, height=500)
for(i in 1:4){
    rnd <-matrix(rnorm(100*100),100,100)
    s_rnd<-raster(rnd)
    extent(s_rnd)<-extent(bk)/i
    crs(s_rnd) <- crs(bk)
    plot(bk, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, box=FALSE)   
    plot(s_rnd, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, box=FALSE,add=TRUE)   
}
dev.off()
system(paste0("convert -delay 40 Rplot*.png ","Test.gif" ))
file.remove(list.files(pattern="^Rplot.*\\.png$"))
```

[image]

Comment: The easy way is to remove the blank plots `fl<-list.files(pattern="^Rplot.*\\.png$");
file.remove(fl[c(seq(1,length(fl),by=2))])
` and then generate the gif